# Castle Windsor: How do you add a call to a factory facility not in xml?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I know how to tell Castle Windsor to resolve a reference from a factory's method using XML, but can I do it programmatically via the Container.AddComponent() interface?  If  not is there any other way to do it from code?

**EDIT:**
There seems to be some confusion so let me clarify, I am looking for a way to do the following in code:

```
<facilities>
   <facility
        id="factory.support"
        type="Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility, Castle.MicroKernel"
    />

</facilities>

<components>

    <component
        id="CustomerRepositoryFactory"
        type="ConsoleApplication2.CustomerRepositoryFactory, ConsoleApplication2"
    />

    <component
        id="CustomerRepository"
        service="ConsoleApplication2.ICustomerRepository, ConsoleApplication2"
        type="ConsoleApplication2.CustomerRepository, ConsoleApplication2"
        factoryId="CustomerRepositoryFactory"
        factoryCreate="Create"
    />

</components>
```

([from this codebetter article on factory support in windsor and spring.net](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2007/12/13/factory-method-support-in-castle-windsor-and-spring-net.aspx))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the Unit Test FactorySupportTestCase (which are your friends):

```
[Test]
    public void FactorySupport_UsingProxiedFactory_WorksFine()
    {
        container.AddFacility("factories", new FactorySupportFacility());
        container.AddComponent("standard.interceptor", typeof(StandardInterceptor));
        container.AddComponent("factory", typeof(CalulcatorFactory));

        AddComponent("calculator", typeof(ICalcService), typeof(CalculatorService), "Create");

        ICalcService service = (ICalcService) container["calculator"];

        Assert.IsNotNull(service);
    }

    private void AddComponent(string key, Type service, Type type, string factoryMethod)
    {
        MutableConfiguration config = new MutableConfiguration(key);
        config.Attributes["factoryId"] = "factory";
        config.Attributes["factoryCreate"] = factoryMethod;
        container.Kernel.ConfigurationStore.AddComponentConfiguration(key, config);
        container.Kernel.AddComponent(key, service, type);
    }
```