# Castle Windsor: How do I register a factory method, when the underlying type isn't accessible to my assembly?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a project where my business layer is constructed using DI, but I'm trying to go an additional step and use Windsor to manage object construction.

Let's just say I have a pre-existing data layer (that I don't want to modify), that can be accessed via the following interface:

```
interface IDataFactory {
   IDataService Service { get; }
}
```

A series of classes in my business layer depend on the services exposed through IDataFactory:

```
IFactory factory = DataFactory.NewFactory();
IBusinessService service = new ConcreteBusinessService(factory.Service);
```

I understand that in order to register IBusinessService to the Castle Windsor container, I'd use code similar to this:

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddComponent("businessService", typeof(IBusinessService), typeof(ConcreteBusinessService));
```

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to register services from my data layer, using the my existing factory object.  In essence, I'd like to say:

```
container.AddComponent("dataService", typeof(IDataService), factory.service);
```

Windsor seems to want me to say **container.AddComponent("dataService", typeof(IDataService), typeOf(SomeConcreteDataService)**), but in this instance, ConcreteDataService is internal to that assembly, and thus not accessible in mine.

How would I go about wiring up the data service, given that SomeConcreteDataService isn't known to my assembly?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238/castle-windsor-how-do-you-add-a-call-to-a-factory-facility-not-in-xml) is very similar to my own, except in my case, the AddComponent("calculator", typeof(ICalcService), typeof(CalculatorService), "Create"); call wouldn't work -- CalculatorService would be internal to another assembly, not available to the assembly wiring up the container.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using Windsor 2.0:

```
[TestFixture]
public class WindsorTests {
    public interface IDataService {}

    public class DataService: IDataService {}

    public interface IDataFactory {
        IDataService Service { get; }
    }

    public class DataFactory: IDataFactory {
        public IDataService Service {
            get { return new DataService(); }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void FactoryTest() {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>();
        container.AddComponent<IDataFactory, DataFactory>();
        container.Register(Component.For<IDataService>().UsingFactory((IDataFactory f) => f.Service));
        var service = container.Resolve<IDataService>();
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(DataService), service);
    }
}
```

See the [fluent API wiki page](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/fluent-registration-api.md) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The answer is, you don't need to worry about the implementation type:

```
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.AddFacility("factories", new FactorySupportFacility());
    container.AddComponent("standard.interceptor", typeof(StandardInterceptor));
    container.AddComponent("factory", typeof(DataFactory));

    MutableConfiguration config = new MutableConfiguration("dataService");
    config.Attributes["factoryId"] = "factory";
    config.Attributes["factoryCreate"] = "get_Service";
    container.Kernel.ConfigurationStore.AddComponentConfiguration("dataService", config);
    container.Kernel.AddComponent("dataService", typeof(IDataService));

    IDataService dataService = (IDataService) container["dataService"];
```

I had a "whoa" moment when I saw it execute successfully, because I hadn't passed in the specific implementation type to Kernel.AddComponent()